# Where can I find the calculations of Google Cardboard?

Tags: google-cardboard

Where can I find the calculations of cardboard?

Example:

- A calculation about distance from lens to my eyes
- A calculation about radious of lens
- A calculation about field of views
- A calculation about focal lenght of lens
- ....

I downloaded document of Google, but it not provides what i want. Because it is too "step-by-step" and i can't see any line explain why i have to select that parameter of components? If i don't want to use 45mm for focal lenght of lens? If i want to use tablet?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AB is phone screen

O is a len

[image]

This is simple function:

[image]

You can be based on this function to calculate distance of lens, eyes, phone screen.

You can ask:" Where i can find OA' "
With normal person, OA' is infinite, With myope, [image]

Example:

I use lens have F = 45 mm, I am a myope and my number of glasses is 3 => OA' = 333 mm => OA = 396 mm

Comment: Hi, I have a hyperopia, my glasses number is +4. A I understand, your number is -3, not 3. Should I use a plus sign in your equation instead of minus? 1/OF = 1/OA + 1/OA'? So OA' is 250mm, and OA would be about 54.8?

Comment: @SWilk I think you can just considered as normal person, so OA is infinite for you

Answer (score 0):

You can find the exact specifications on the [Google Cardboard website](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/manufacturers/), in the Manufacturers section. There you can download the kit which provides the details you're looking for.

Comment: I downloaded document of Google, but it not provides what i want. Because it is too "step-by-step" and i can't see any line explain why i have to select that parameter of components? If i don't want use 45mm for focal lenght of lens? If i want use tablet?...